# Persisting network names irrespective of network address

Tags: wifi, udev, network-interface

We are in process of developing custom linux device with unifil wifi card. Whenever we change wireless device with in device urules changing wlan index based on ATTR{address}. Is there a way to tell not to look for ATTR{address} and assign wlan0 as adapter name for every wireless device?

Answer (score 0):

Rumor has it the `append` line addition of `biosdevname=0` used to turn that off, though now `net.ifnames=0` is preferred. Or add both! This will need to be done in the grub configuration or as shown here the pxe boot configs, e.g.

```
label centos7
        kernel centos7/vmlinuz
        append initrd=centos7/initrd.img ks=... ksdevice=eth0 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0
```

Comment: We are not using centros7 OS, We are using Arm Linnux kernel version 3.6.9. Is there such setting in kernel?

Comment: Hmm, not sure where "Arm Linux 3.6.9" came from, though it sounds like something with udev on it, as Linux did not use to name devices such. What bootloader is it using? This might be lilo, elilo, grub, or grub2; hints of this could probably be found under `/etc` or `/boot`...

Comment: @Jammy1: whatever Linux you're using, `net.ifnames=0` will force it to revert to the old naming scheme (eth0, wlan0, eth.). I've been using this for all my machines since the day this new "invention" entered the kernel, and this flags just works great.